# Protected Sheet Creating Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have kind of a paradox problem with my macro enabled workbook (paradox meaning that the very same commands work just fine in another protected sheet of mine):

Once I start protecting my Worksheet, the commands ".Interior.Color" and ".Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle" will continue to produce "application-defined or object-defined errors"

Here's an example of one macro showing that very error:

```
Private Sub Con1_Click()

Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="bla"

Worksheets("SOLL").Range("N23:S25").ClearContents

Range("N23:S25").Interior.Color = RGB(225, 225, 225)
Range("P23:Q25").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone

Sheet1.Protect Password:="bla"

End Sub
```

Note: I added the Unprotect/Protect commands to get rid of other errors that kept occuring. Like I said, the two commands work just fine in another sheet, so I really can't figure out any source of the problem. If anyone has encountered similar problems yet or has any ideas for solutions, I'd be glad for the help!

Comment: To my mind, before those 2 lines (`Range("N23:S25")` and `Range("P23:Q25")`) you should explicitly state which worksheet are you referring to. Like in the first case: `Worksheets("SOLL").Range("N23:S25")`.

Comment: What's the *active* sheet when the macro raises the error? The `Unprotect` method is explicit on `Sheet1`, but the other statements are unqualified to a specific worksheet, so they will execute against the `ActiveSheet`. I would say 10/10 this is the source of your error.

Comment: All commands of that Macro refer to the 'ActiveSheet', I tried adding a specific reference to the active sheet in all commands, but the error still keeps appearing. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the protection process, because the macro works fine once I delete the 'Protect' command.

Comment: Maybe the protection settings are not identical? Or maybe the target cells are not locked in one of the workbooks?

Comment: Ok, I believe we might be getting closer to the cause, I didn't have the Range("N23:S25") locked, just changed it. Unfortunately a run-time error appears now whenever activate the macro, saying "the cell or chart you're trying to change is protected and therefore read-only" which keeps me confused. Isn't the 'Unprotect' and 'Protect' command meant to bypass the read-only feature by temporarily deactivating protective effects?

Comment: If you open VBE, in Project window you see modules. For all the worksheets one name is enclosed in brackets, the other is not. Your statement `Worksheets("SOLL")` refers to the enclosed name. And this one `Sheet1.Unprotect` refers to the one which is not enclosed. Maybe in your sub you are unprotecting a different sheet than you actually need?

Answer (score 1):

Too long/confusing to put in comments, so I will put this as an answer, perhaps it will shed some light on your problem. You say:

> All commands of that Macro refer to the 'ActiveSheet',

But this is **not necessarily** true. Observe the three different constructs you're using to refer to worksheets:

1. Explicit reference to a worksheet by its codename: `Sheet1.Unprotect ...`
2. Explicit reference to a worksheet by its sheet name: `Worksheets("SOLL")...`
3. Implicit reference to *whatever worksheet is active at run-time*: `Range("N23:S25")..`

There are many circumstances which falsify your assertion that "all commands of that macro refer to the `ActiveSheet`. For example, `Sheet1` may (or may not) be the same as `Worksheets("SOLL")`.

So, potentially this code is referring to as many as three different worksheet objects! Only the implicit, unqualified `Range` statements can be guaranteed to refer to the `ActiveSheet`.

Perhaps this test will shed some light on the matter. Modify your code as follows:

```
Private Sub Con1_Click()

MsgBox "Sheet1.Name is: " & Sheet1.Name
MsgBox "Worksheets("SOLL").CodeName is: " & Worksheets("SOLL").Codename
MsgBox "The activesheet is: " & ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

You may also add the following information, which could be useful to those offering assistance:

1. Where is this button located? (On which worksheet?)
2. Where is the code for the button event located? In a sheet module or a standard module?

Comment: First of all thank you for your advise. When I wrote "All commands of that Macro refer to the 'ActiveSheet'" it was my intention to clarify that SOLL = Sheet1 = the sheet causing problems; in my workbook there are currently two sheets using buttons and the commands that allegedly cause the error in Sheet1 are not making troubles in Sheet2; the attribution seems not to be the problem, because the error keeps occuring even if I restate the command with the same sheet label.
1. The Option Button (and the others causing the same error) is on Sheet1
2. The Code is located in Microsoft Excel Objects

Comment: "Microsoft Excel Objects" is not enough information. Does the code reside in a *standard* code module, or does it reside in one of the Worksheet modules? Is this a Form Control or an ActiveX control? Are the similar controls on the other worksheet Form Control or ActiveX?  There's a lot of unsanswered questions so far...